# How does a web beacon(web bug) work?

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, ads, web

Can anybody explain exactly how a web beacon works? I know they're generally used by advertising platforms but i can't really find a good explanation on how they're working.

I know that cookies aren't accessible cross-domain. A web beacon is an image that sends a request to the server, and the server adds a cookie to the response, right?  So how can it be accessed on different domains?

Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When an HTML page is downloaded the browser parses the page and looks for additional resources needed to display the page, such as images.  For each image it finds the browser makes another request to a server in the background.  When servers receive requests, they usually log the request to monitor load on the server, and record information about who sent the request and where it came from.  A web beacon is a tiny invisible graphic that generates a request to the tracking firm's server.  They record the request in their logs and then analyze their logs to see who went where and did what and when.

When returning the image from their servers to the browser, they can also send down information to be added to a cookie.  There are third-party cookies that can be tracked across domains.  If you come back to the site, and the beacon request is made again, that cookie will also be sent up in the request to the server and the tracking firm will have more information about you.

Think about this.  Even though you are visiting ***myfavoritesite.com*** the web beacon image is being requested from ***trackers.com***.  The cookie they create is assigned/locked to their domain, trackers.com.  But if you then surf over to ***myotherfavoritesite.com***, and they too are sending web beacons to ***trackers.com***, the cookie will essentially be shared between the two sites.  There are more considerations here, but that is the basic premise.

Answer (score 1):

Bug bug (also known as Web beacon) is very important tools commonly used by online advertiser as marketing or advertisement analysis tool for tracking and monitoring the activity of users on a website or marketing content i.e: blog or email. An expert advertiser inserts web bug in his content (usually on website and email) in order track how many people opened a particular content, on which application and country his content is being viewed. So, whenever advertisement display by third-party just know that you are being tracked for marketing analysis purpose.

Bug bug tools are provided freely or premium mostly by CRM service providers like Hubspot CRM, Freshsales CRM, Salesforce CRM, etc. However, a Web bug PHP code can also be used for this if tracking service by CRM provider is not available. [Continue reading](https://blog.olalekanadmin.pro/blog/2020/02/24/information-gathering-tool-how-to-use-web-bug-to-track-user-online/)

Answer (score 0):

And instead of going off and creating one using Php and Apache redirects, my vote is that you go to http://webbeak.com and create one, use it, and track it.  No cost either.